# PATH variable in macOS changes on new tab

Tags: macos, path

I opened terminal and for some purposes I updated my PATH variable. and using terminal tapping Ctl+T opening a new tab for me to work easily on other matters. However I found that a lot of commands suddenly not working in the new tab and when I check my PATH variable with `echo $PATH` it is different from what I updated in the old tab.

So I realize the $PATH in the old tab is different from the one that is in the new tab.

What is the reason? How can I fix this issue? I just wanna refer to the same PATH so that I can use my commands

Comment: Are the new tabs getting the old PATH (before you updated it), or is it different from that too?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just got the answer. It was because by doing `export PATH=$PATH:.....` is not a permanent change on the `PATH` variable. Instead if we are looking for a permanent change, we should do `vim ~/.bash_profile` and add the PATH in there instead.